# Bad performance on sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

```
SELECT orcamentos.id
FROM usuarios, clientes, empresas, orcamentos
WHERE 
(
    (
        clientes.nome LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
        AND clientes.email=usuarios.usuario
    )
    AND orcamentos.cliente=usuarios.id
)
OR 
(
    (
        (
            empresas.razao_social LIKE '%VARIAVEL%' 
            OR empresas.nome_fantasia LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
        ) 
        AND empresas.email=usuarios.usuario
    ) 
    AND orcamentos.cliente=usuarios.id
)
OR orcamentos.nome_cliente LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
GROUP BY orcamentos.id;
```

I have this query which works properly but has performance issues. I would like some tips of query structure to optimeze this, say: in this case is better a `join`, etc. The SGBD is mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an `EXPLAIN` statement? That might be a start.

Comment: What's the execution plan show?  My guess is the LIKE '%VAR%' in multiple places is causing the biggest bottleneck.  Anyway you can avoid the double %?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I think your AND/OR logic is going to result in a cartesian product.  If you fall through to `OR (orcamentos.nome_cliente LIKE '%VARIAVEL%')`, you aren't ever specifying any join criteria.

Comment: Minus the fact you haven't said what database your on, provided the table DDL, or an explain plan it will be hard for you to get what you want. All I can help you with given your content is all your LIKE '%VARIAVEL%' will most likely cause a full table scan.

Comment: I would also comment that excessive use of parenthesis may make it difficult to read.

Comment: @swasheck he's just updated the post to say MySQL. I'd argue the best thing for this would be a full text index and losing the full table scans.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query is clearer:

```
SELECT orcamentos.id
FROM usuarios
join orcamentos on orcamentos.cliente=usuarios.id
left join clientes on clientes.email=usuarios.usuario
left join empresas on empresas.email=usuarios.usuario
WHERE 
  COALESCE(clientes.nome,'') + COALESCE(empresas.razao_social,'') +
  COALESCE(empresas.nome_fantasia,'') + orcamentos.nome_cliente LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
GROUP BY orcamentos.id;
```

note which are left joins, you can make orcamentos a left join too but then you will have a row with null in your result set.

You will still have performance problems.  Searches like `clientes.nome LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'` are slow since indexes can't be used.  Some SQL platforms have the CONTAINS keyword but are still slow unless you are using a product that has full text search features and it has been enabled for the columns being searched.  A full table scan is needed to find an arbitrary string in a field.  Indexes are much faster.

If you always are searching for the same thing there are tricks you can do to speed up that search.

Comment: +1, I didn't think about concatenating the strings together and then compare.  Better than comparing 4 separate times.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following query:

```
SELECT orcamentos.id
FROM usuarios
  INNER JOIN orcamentos ON orcamentos.cliente = usuarios.id
  LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.email = usuarios.usuario
  LEFT JOIN empresas ON empresas.email = usuarios.usuario
WHERE clientes.nome LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
  OR empresas.razao_social LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
  OR empresas.nome_fantasia LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
  OR orcamentos.nome_cliente LIKE '%VARIAVEL%'
GROUP BY orcamentos.id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be an edit to the question not a answer to the question?

Comment: @Bob it would be an invalid edit, since it would change the behaviour.

Comment: My bad, I thought you just reformatted. Though none of us will ever no in what way the behavior changes without the original explain plan.

Comment: this query can return a row with null which the original query couldn't